# How to fetch body data from IHttpActionResult in MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller, httprequest

I have ApiController which receives a specific object of a class. That works perfect but what if, HTTP Request which contains a body with JSON is not matching with the object of a class? I will receive a null value of object because there is not a match between JSON and object of a class. My question is, how to get original JSON request when a user sends JSON with an incorrect format?

```
public class Document{
string name;
int number;
}
```

JSON REQUEST

```
{
   "name":"Default name",
   "number":91526861713"
}
```

JSON IS INCORRECT BECAUSE DATA TYPE OF number is int, not string "234" !
Automatically documentObject in function is equal to null.
How to get original JSON REQUEST?

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Receiving([FromBody]Document documentObject)
{

}
```

Comment: how to post request code? can you share snipet code?

Comment: I'm sending with POSTMAN and I wanna get an original body from request.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Request.Content` , But `output` is `raw` string.

like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Receiving([FromBody]Document documentObject)
{
     var content = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     return Json(content); // output => "name=xxx&number=123"
}
```

Comment: I tried with that but this method does not return whole original JSON from the body request...

Comment: you can cast output string data to `json` simply with `split`.

Comment: The object of the class is just an example, the real class and JSON is much bigger. Real Question is, how to read incorrect format of JSON. When a client tries to send incorrect JSON I need to see why that JSON is not correct. For example, "JSON is not correct because you forgot to add quotation marks on your string data type"  ... So, the problem is, when the user sends the incorrect format of JSON, IHTTPActionResults receives an object with null value...